# How do i plot this polynomial fraction using numpy and matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The task is to print quotient and remainder of this [polynomial fraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNITu.png) and then plot the original function and the quotient. I figured out how to plot the quotient, but what is the best way to plot f(x)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

px = np.poly1d([1, -7, 15, -21, 36])
qx = np.poly1d([1, -7, 6])        

hx, rx = np.polydiv(px, qx)

print("\nh(x):")
print("\n", hx)
print("\nr(x):")
print(rx, "\n")

x = np.arange(20)
y = hx(x)
plt.grid(color='black', linestyle='dotted')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to define a x-range and evaluate the function. Straight forward:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

px = np.poly1d([1, -7, 15, -21, 36])
qx = np.poly1d([1, -7, 6])        

hx, rx = np.polydiv(px, qx)

print("\nh(x):")
print("\n", hx)
print("\nr(x):")
print(rx, "\n")

x = np.linspace(0,20,101)
f = (x**4 - 7*x**3 + 15*x**2 - 21*x + 36)/(x**2 - 7*x + 6)
y = hx(x)
plt.grid(color='black', linestyle='dotted')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x,f)
plt.show()
```

[image]